# What's the difference between Document.addField and Document.setField in solrj?

Tags: java, search, solr, solrj

While adding documents to an index in `solr`, I've noticed there are two ways to add data one is to `addField` another is to `setField`. Can you tell me when to use which method?

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.setField("field_name", data);
doc.addField("field_name_2", data2);
```

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/SolrInputDocument.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SolrInputDocument.addField()` - it will add another value to any existing values for the field.It works like an append

`SolrInputDocument.setField()` - it will overwrite anything that is already there.Discard existing values and start with a fresh list of values.